# Why image not found error come in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

Could you please tell me Why I am getting image not found error ?I used this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-viewer
Follow all steps but getting error image not found.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u26jb5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  images='https://images.pexels.com/photos/144240/goat-lamb-little-grass-144240.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array as a source for the images even if you have just one:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  images=['https://images.pexels.com/photos/144240/goat-lamb-little-grass-144240.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb']
}
```

Comment: what is the reason for this?

Comment: This is not the same [src] as for img, he is using ngx-image-viewer component. (<ngx-image-viewer  [src]="images" ></ngx-image-viewer>)

Comment: And the reason is that this isn't single photo viewer, but you can navigate between multiple images which sources you define in the array.